# How can I show some description in the "All Posts" view of a custom post type in Dashboard?

Tags: custom-post-types, dashboard

I want to show some short description in the **All `post_type`** view of a custom post type in the WordPress Admin Dashboard.

For example:

> For this custom post type, my shortcode is this `[shortcode]`.

Is there any way to show this before all posts?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The title says "how can I show shortcode description" but in your description, it says "I want to show some short description". Which one is correct? Wanna show a short description or shortcode description?

Comment: want to show some short description, i couldn't make up the title, please omit it

Comment: the problem is simple, but i couldn't get the proper solution

Comment: Post edited based on the comments and accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter `views_{$this->screen->id}` is fired just after the title of post edit screen has been print to screen, so it's a safe place to just echo what you want.

So you can simply check here:

```
function post_type_desc( $views ){    
    printf('<h4>%s</h4>', __('Your description here.') ); // echo 
    return $views; // return original input unchanged
}
add_filter("views_edit-POST_TYPE_HERE", 'post_type_desc');
```

Replace `your_post_type` here in `POST_TYPE_HERE`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: where i will put post type, $post_type = get_post_type_object($screen->post_type);

Comment: You can replace your post_type_name in "POST_TYPE_HERE" it in the add_filter ()

Comment: @NayeemHyderRiddhi, I have updated code what you want.

Comment: Glad to know that, cheers!